# what is the difference about Unity-iPhone and Unity-iPhone-simulator in xcode

Tags: xcode, unity-game-engine, simulator

when I use the xcode for compiling the game what is built from unity , I notice that if I choose  Unity-iPhone-simulator ,there are many errors ,after I choose the Unity-iPhone ,the project runs successfully , I want to know the reson about this . Thank you for the sharer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somewhat related, from [Unity IOS Basics](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/iphone-basic.html):

> Can Unity-built games run in the iPhone Simulator?
>
> A: No, but Unity iOS can build to iPad Simulator if you're using the latest SDK. However the simulator itself is not very useful for Unity because it does not simulate all inputs from iOS or properly emulate the performance you get on the iPhone/iPad. You should test out gameplay directly inside Unity using the iPhone/iPad as a remote control while it is running the Unity Remote application. Then, when you are ready to test performance and optimize the game, you publish to iOS devices.

As for why iPhone-Simulator fails, likely you are using an incorrect iPhone SDK.  Try setting SDk version to 4.1.

The community at large seems to regard the Simulator builder as broken and that you should stick with native builds or using the Unity remote for testing.  Some information [sourced from here.](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/62800-iPhone-Simulator)